# Float and double in c#

Tags: c#

Is it necessary to specify `f` while initiating a float type variable.

```
float a =3455.67f;
```

If I declare and initiate it as

```
float a = 3455.67;
```

Then what will happen?

Comment: @samm yes otherwise compiler gives error "Literal of type double cannot be implicitly converted to type 'float'; use an 'F' suffix to create a literal of this type".

Comment: The question should be re-written as "why is the F mandatory" rather than "what will happen"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx) on `float` says:

> By default, a real numeric literal on the right side of the assignment
>   operator is treated as `double`. Therefore, to initialize a `float`
>   variable, use the suffix `f` or `F`.

This means that if you do `float a = 3455.67;` then the compiler will refuse to implicitly convert the `double` to a `float`.

Comment: I always wondered why was this a mandatory syntax. Apparently what really happens in the compiler level is that the right side of the equal operation is first assigned as double, before being assigned to the left had type. This sounds weird, as the F makes the explicit left "float" typing contingent

Comment: More interesting documentation, this is required because double does not implicitly cast to float (or interestingly enough, anything else). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx

Answer (score 3):

By default, a real numeric literal on the right side of the assignment operator is treated as double. Therefore, to initialize a float variable, use the suffix f or F, as in the following example:

```
float x = 3.5F;
```

If you do not use the suffix in the previous declaration, you will get a compilation error because you are trying to store a double value into a float variable.

for more details look at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/b1e65aza.aspx)

Comment: -1: Copy/pasting from MSDN without further ado isn't really the way to go.

Comment: yes I know but better to give some info here that put on only the URL link to msdn link after some time can be broken

Answer (score 2):

This :

```
float a = 3455.67;
```

will not compile. 3455.67 is a double constant and C# will permit you to assign this value to a float variable.

Use:

```
float f = (float)3455.67;
```

or you will have to specify the "f" format suffix.

Comment: Why is float to double conversion considered widening, while double to float isn't? Logically, the reverse should be true, since e.g. (float)((double)0.1) and (float)((double)1E38*10.0) will yield (float)0.1 and (float)+INF [meaning something greater than 3.4E38], both of which are correct. By contrast, (double)(0.1f) or (double)((float)1E38f*10.0f) will yield (double)0.10000000149011612 and (double)+INF [meaning something greater than 1.79E308], both of which are wrong. Casts from more specific classes to less specific are widening, while reverse casts are narrowing. Why are floats backward?