# C# How to pass in number as float to functions ?

Tags: c#, decimal

I created a validation function as below:

```
public static T getAsDigit<T>( this Textbox tb, float min, float max  ){
}
```

Most of the time, the validation range is specificed in integers. It works fine. But when I try to pass in decimals, it give me error sth like `can't convert double to float`, I have to change defination to double.

I am new to C#, how can I pass in the digits as float ? without doing sth unintuitive like `Convert.toFloat('1.3')`.

My use case only requires 3 decimal place precision, value range 0.000 ~ 10.000. Is there any disadvantage in using float versus double in C#? Since I used and saw people use float a lot in sql when decimal() is optional.

Comment: why doesn't you just change the signature of that function to accept double?

Comment: Releated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327142/float-and-double-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Frode, Thanks, that's what I did, but I am still curious how to write float numbers without casting it every time.

Comment: @Magnus, thanks, excatly the error I get, though the question is different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `f` literal: `getAsDigit(1.34f)`

Or cast value to float `getAsDigit((float)1.34)`

Comment: Thanks, I though there should be some notations like that. Shame, I  failed to find it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the double to flow so i recommend you do

```
float.Parse(x)
```

the cleaner option would be to create a new var and convert it to float there instead of in the injection so something like this:

```
double x = 1.3;

var newFloat = float.Parse(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to write a validation for the value of the `TextBox`.

You can upgrade your method to make it generic for all value type `struct`

```
        public static T getAsDigit<T>(this TextBox tb, T min, T max) where T : struct, IComparable<T>
        {
            var valueConverted = default(T);
            try
            {
               valueConverted = (T)Convert.ChangeType(tb.Text, typeof(T));
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                //do something you want, rethown i.e
            }
            if (valueConverted.CompareTo(max) > 0)
                return max;

            if (valueConverted.CompareTo(min) < 0)
                return min;

            return valueConverted;
        }
```

And you can simply pass the type you want.

```
string a = "10.5"; // suppose that a is TextBox.Text
var b = a.getAsDigit<float>(10,11); // return 10.5f
var c = a.getAsDigit<decimal>(11,12); //return 11d
var d = a.getAsDigit<double>(9,10); //return 10d
```